# Reinstalling GUI in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, lightdm, gui

Accidentally, I've installed the package slick-greeter while trying to change the background picture of the login screen of Ubuntu 18.04 (it wasn't what I was looking for). While installing that package, I selected lightdm.

After rebooting, my system looks like the previous versions of Ubuntu, much uglier (may I have installed unintentionally Unity?). I don't know exactly what happened, so I'd like to just reinstall the default GUI of Ubuntu 18.04.

I've tried to again enable gdm3, but I've just managed to make the login screen look like it did before my mistake.

This is the issue:

[image]

As you can see, the top bar doesn't look like Ubuntu 18.04 and the dash is the same as in Unity.

Comment: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3` will reset gdm3 (display-manager) to default causing you to be asked which greeter you want to use; be it lightdm, gdm3, or slick-greeter (or whatever you've installed).  I'm assuming you didn't remove it (just not use it)

Comment: If your login screen looks like before then what's your issue? (- slick-greeter does not install any additional sessions.

Comment: @guiverc already tried that; it didn't ask me anything but thanks anyway! Please check the picture I've just added.

Comment: @doug the login screen is fixed, but the rest of the system look like the pictura I've just posted.

Comment: Well that's unity. Just log out and at the login screen choose Ubuntu, that should log you into a gnome(shell) session. If there are no session choices  at the login screen (under a gear icon) then install the `ubuntu-desktop` package & reboot.